# MySQL Not Unique

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm having a trouble with MySQL

I really don't know what is wrong with these query, it should return a table with three columns, but it keeps returning this error: "Not unique table/alias: 'departamentos'."

```
SELECT empresas.nome, departamentos.nomeDepartamento, funcionarios.nomeFuncionario 
FROM ((
empresas INNER JOIN departamentos ON empresas.id = departamentos.idEmpresas) 
INNER JOIN departamentos ON departamentos.id = funcionarios.idDepartamentos);
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You have the same table name twice (duplicated, not unique) in the `FROM` clause, that is what the error means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `departamentos` table name is specified twice in the `FROM` clause, which is what the error means.

You likely meant to do:

```
SELECT empresas.nome, departamentos.nomeDepartamento, funcionarios.nomeFuncionario 
  FROM empresas 
    INNER JOIN departamentos ON empresas.id = departamentos.idEmpresas
    INNER JOIN funcionarios ON departamentos.id = funcionarios.idDepartamentos;
```